# Determine the result of a Conditional Formatting formula programmatically for a given worksheet in C#, Vsto

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Is there a way to run the conditional formatting formulae through an OpenXML or Interop.Excel method or a parser to check if the conditions are fulfilled for a given worksheet.
Ex. If a conditional formatting formula is "=$B$3>25%", for a given worksheet, is there a way to check if this condition results in true or false.

Comment: =IF($B$3>25,TRUE,FALSE) would be a start.

Comment: I am looking for a C# method where I can pass the rule as an argument and get the result true or false.

Comment: Well you tagged Excel and Excel formula so I obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for this purpose you can use the [Application.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) function and pass to it the formula of format condition of the tested cell. Is it what you are looking for?

---

Simple example:

```
using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static bool EvaluateConditionalFormattingFormula(MSExcel.Range cell)
{
    MSExcel.FormatConditions formatConditions = cell.FormatConditions;

    if (formatConditions == null || formatConditions.Count == 0)
        return false;

    MSExcel.FormatCondition formatCondition = formatConditions[1];
    bool result = cell.Application.Evaluate(formatCondition.Formula1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Dusek, Thanks a lot. I can work on that. Application.Evaluate was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.